# How to align the header menu from left? i see a unexpected margin on left. Help please

Tags: html, css

http://cooking.comyr.com/

I am creating a header menu using CSS. you can see that on above URL.
HTML code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Let's Be Foodie | Homemade Restaurant Style Food</title>
<link href="Style/main_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<div id="Header">
        <ul>
              <li><a href="#" title="Home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Recipes"><span>Recipes</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Recipe Finder"><span>Recipe Finder</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Foodie Blog"><span>Foodie Blog</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Foodie Forum"><span>Foodie Forum</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Tips & Tricks"><span>Tips & Tricks</span></a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!--Header class ends here-->
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS is

```
#Header {
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
    /* font-size:93%;*/
    line-height: 45px;
    background-color: #F00;
}
#Header ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #03C;
    margin:auto;
}
#Header li {
      display:inline;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      text-align:center;
      font-family:jokerman;
      font-size:18px
      }
#Header a {
      float:left;
      background:url("Green.png") no-repeat left top;
      margin:0;
      width:150px;
      text-decoration:none;

}
#Header a span {
      display:block;
      background:url("Green.png") no-repeat right top;
      color:#F00;
      float:none;
}

#Header a:hover span {
      color:#FFF;
      background:url("Orange.png") no-repeat right top;
}
#Header a:hover {
      background:url("Orange.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

How can i get rid of extra margin on left?

URL to see my issue is : http://cooking.comyr.com/

Comment: #Header ul { padding: 0; }

Comment: Anytime. Best of luck on the rest of the site!

Comment: Hi Darren, I see one more issue in that header where there is a small white gap at the beginning of header. Can you please let me know what change i should do to overcome this?

Comment: that's likely the `body { margin: 0; }` that yoav answered with. really you should start out with a css reset since it makes everything so much easier.  

check out [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body tag has a default margin property. Use the following CSS code to get rid of the default margin:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```